# Joomla 3 redirect out of iframe in breezing forms

Tags: iframe, joomla, joomla3.0, breezingforms

I have the following problem:

Joomla 3.2.1 with breezing forms (latest version)

Since I needed 2 forms on the same page, one of them had to be inside an iframe (its an option that can be used with breezing forms plugin). So after configuring that, I need the form after submit to redirect to a thank you page, which is a joomla article. The problem is that after redirect the thank you page loads inside the iframe.

The only way I found to break out is by using javascript or `target"_parent"`, but I can only add some php in "Submit pieces"->"End Submit", which is where the redirect is. The redirect is a php function like so:

```
JFactory::getApplication()->redirect('http://....');
```

Maybe someone has an idea on how to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here:
[BreezingForms knowlege base](http://crosstec.de/support/index.php?pid=knowledgebase&cmd=viewentclient&id=27)

It seem to have some problem with real urls, but SEF url redirect works fine.